# Hyperledger Fabric: Do we need to pass TLS cert/key files while joining channel?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have a multi-org network fabric network up and running from different hosts.

The docker containers for the peers have TLS enabled. The build configuration of the peer:

```
- CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
- CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
- CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
- CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
```

While creating and joining the channel I followed [byfn docs](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/build_network.html#create-join-channel) and did not supply the TLS cert/file of the peer while joining the channel. All the peers were able to join the channel.

However, when I tried to fetch the newest block using `peer channel fetch newest -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c examplechannel`, I got the error:

> Serve failed to complete security handshake from "ip:43402": tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake

Further, I referred [this doc](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/enable_tls.html) on TLS and [this doc](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/commands/peerchannel.html#peer-channel-fetch)
on passing TLS certs of the peer with the above fetch command:

```
peer channel fetch newest -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c examplechannel --tls --certfile $CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE --keyfile $CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE --cafile $CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE
```

This gave a new error:

> grpc: Server.Serve failed to complete security handshake from "ip:43496": remote error: tls: bad certificate

[Debugging TLS issues](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/enable_tls.html#debugging-tls-issues) doc states that this happens when the server does not trust the client certificate. So in my case, I infer that the orderer is not trusting the certificate that the peer is passing.

So

1. Does it mean that I was supposed to pass TLS_CERT, TLS_KEY and TLS_ROOT cert while proposing a channel join from this peer?
2. If #1 is true, can I pass these certificates without bringing down the network and rejoining the channel with certs?
3. While creating the channel, it uses orderer's ca-cert. Also, when submitting anchor peer transaction, it uses orderer's ca cert? So am I supposed to use Orderer's ca cert for peer fetch command as well?
4. If #3 is true, then in a production environment, do we need to build up the peer containers such that it contains orderer's ca-cert?

Comment: when you enable the TLS, you need pass the TLS when invoke all the peer commands.

Comment: @LipingHuang, Is there a way to pass those certs when the network is still up?

Comment: you need pass the correct tls files, that the message from the server, you passed the not validated certificated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple concepts baked into your questions.  It's important to understand that there is a difference between using the `peer` to run a peer node--`peer node start`-- and using the `peer` as a CLI (e.g. `peer channel fetch`).

When the peer is running as a server, there's no need to pass in crypto material for the channels as the peer actually extracts the required TLS certificate information from the config block passed in the `peer channel join ...` command.

When the peer is running in CLI mode, you do need to provide the the TLS certificate information to connect to the various endpoints.  When communicating with peers, this information is extracted from the peer config (either in `core.yaml` or from the corresponding `CORE_` environment variables).  When communicating with the orderer, there are specific command line flags for setting the TLS material.

Comment: Got it. So any communication with the orderer will need tls cert file of the orderer, right?

Comment: correct ... you need to set the `--cafile` flag to the root CA which issued the TLS cert for the orderer(s)